# How to copy existing data using logical replication connection

Tags: database, postgresql, replication, logical-replication

My problem is that I'm trying to create logical replication and receive updates inside the code. (please do not advise to use **CREATE SUBSCRIPTION** command. It works if I do Postgres -> Postgres migration)
I use github.com/jackc/pgx
But it appears I can create a replication slot and start streaming only for the data that is inserted/deleted after the slot has been created.

But I  need to get all the existing data as well.

AWS DMS can do it somehow. They have full-load + CDC mode for the tables.

I have tried to research Postgres documentation but it seems very unclearly to me.

UPD:

The details are the following:
**Postgres version:** 13 (docker image debezium/postgres:13)
**Create snapshot command:** `CREATE_REPLICATION_SLOT %s LOGICAL %s` 
**Start replication command:** `START_REPLICATION SLOT %s LOGICAL %s`
I've tried to add `USE_SNAPSHOT` arg to create a snapshot command. Because as I got from the documentation it should use the data snapshot for the slot, but every time it throws an error `CREATE_REPLICATION_SLOT ... USE_SNAPSHOT must be called inside a transaction (SQLSTATE XX000)`

Comment: Your choices are like it or not are: 1) `CREATE SUBSCRIPTION`  2)  `ALTER SUBSCRIPTION` with `REFRESH PUBLICATION`

Comment: Don't really get the question/answer :)

Comment: They both have `copy_data` which: *"Specifies whether to copy pre-existing data in the publications that are being subscribed to when the replication starts. The default is true."*.  You will need to provide a complete description of the process you are using to go any further with this. At a minimum 1) Postgres version(s) 2) The command used to create the slot and the command that does the streaming. Bottom line per [Logical replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/logical-replication.html) the replication is done on a publisher/subscriber model.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. The details are following: 
Postgres version: 13 (docker image debezium/postgres:13)
Create snapshot command: `CREATE_REPLICATION_SLOT %s LOGICAL %s`
Start replication command: `START_REPLICATION SLOT %s LOGICAL %s`

I've tried to add `USE_SNAPSHOT` arg to create a snapshot command. Because as I got from the documentation it should use the data snapshot for the slot, but everytime is throws an error `REATE_REPLICATION_SLOT ... USE_SNAPSHOT must be called inside a transaction (SQLSTATE XX000) `

Comment: You need to add this information to the question along with a better description of what you are doing/trying to achieve. Also seems you are directly using the replication mode from here [Streaming Replication Protocol](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/protocol-replication.html).

Comment: Thanks. I'll add it. 
Yes, you are right. I connect to the PG server in replication mode. 
As I'm working on golang tool for logical replication with initial data copying.

Comment: @VladislavLen I had the same problem as you , I also use github.com/jackc/pglogrepl  , Please, if you get the answer, leave it for us to see